# Data label not showing in some pie chart handles Highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

I am having a weird a problem in highchart piechart.

> If the number of points are more than 6 and if one of them having a
>   less percentage of 1.2% the lesser point won't show data labels.

I am not sure whether it is the exact scenario.

This is my javascript file

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [
        {name: "Nike", y: 91.6},
        {name: "Adidas", y: 2.2},
        {name: "Puma", y: 2.0},
        {name: "Skechers", y: 1.6},
        {name: "North face", y: 1.4},
        {name: "Asics", y: 1.2},
    ],
    }],
});
```

And [This is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/kajgn6mh/)

Can any one please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `series.dataLabels.padding : 0` you can show all labels like that:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Brands',
  dataLabels: {
    padding: 0
  },
  data: [{
      name: "Nike",
      y: 91.6
    },
    {
      name: "Adidas",
      y: 0.2
    },
    {
      name: "Puma",
      y: 0.2
    },
    {
      name: "Skechers",
      y: 1.6
    },
    {
      name: "North face",
      y: 0.2
    },
    {
      name: "Asics",
      y: 0.2
    },
  ]
}]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/mds0uof4/)