# Highcharts Donut percentages for less than 1% inconsistent for English and French values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[For Issue 1. In this 0,10% sector is not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKTjM.png)Hi I am using highcharts donut to display percentages with callouts/strokes labels, I am facing below issues:

1. For less than 1% sectors, sectors and callouts/strokes with label are not displayed for French language whereas it works fine for English language.
   For Example: If there is a sector with 0.45% which is displayed in donut for English, not displayed in donut if I change language to French.

2.For less than 1% sectors, sector is not created/dispalyed but callouts/strokes with label are dispalyed. [In this image section is not created for 0,47% and 0,03% but callouts/strokes are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZinZ.png)

3.For less than 1% sectors, callouts/strokes around the donut are not displayed(inconsistent).

4. For less than 1% sectors, callouts/strokes are overlapping which is confusing.

To show all the data labels with low percentage values I used series.dataLabels.padding : 0

[Data label not showing in some pie chart handles Highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672874/data-label-not-showing-in-some-pie-chart-handles-highchart)`enter code here`

https://jsfiddle.net/core972/mds0uof4/

Thank you in advance.

[Single indicator center alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1vRU.png)

Comment: May I see your demo? I don't think that the demo which you shared is related to your issue - I mean you mentioned something about using French and it is confusing to me.

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel thank you for taking your time.. I have attached Image hope it will help. In the image 0,10% section is not displayed- hope this will help

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case and it seems that points are visible: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cb21smn6/ Notice that value 0.03 is almost invisible because comparing to rest of the values is much smaller, so chart render this proportion properly.

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel can you please try same in the French format as in French 0.03 is 0,03 I am getting issue for the French numbers as in the image attached above for issue 1.

Comment: Highcharts requires data in the number format. 0,03 is not a number but is a string. If you want to use it you will need to write some parser function which will change the format to number. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel if there is a single indicator for a donut chart for example at the bottom of donut, chart is not dynamically center aligned. Image attached above for reference named "single indicator center alignment". Chart is taking top padding too even if there is no indicator. Is there any option to center align chart if there is no indicator?  Chart should not leave place for indicator it should move to the top.

Comment: could you reproduce this case on some online editor which I could work on?